# Why is the ForEach only registering the first element from the array?

Tags: javascript, foreach

### Goal

I'm trying to limit the height of each **Award Category** to the total height of 3 award divs. The reason for this is that it is dynamic and the height may vary depending on what the user puts in for the award info.

Link to CodePen for more context: https://codepen.io/Kaleshe/pen/QWpdJQq

### Problem

For some reason, only the first element is being registered and I can't put my finger on why.

According to the error the next item in the loop is undefined, but it is picked up if I console log it outside of the loop like this `awardCatContainers[0].querySelectorAll('.award')`

### Code

```
const awardCatContainers = document.querySelectorAll( '.award-category-container' );
const button = document.querySelector( '.award .button' );

awardCatContainers.forEach( (container) => {
    let awards = container.querySelectorAll( '.award' );
    let height = getContainerHeight(awards);

    container.style.maxHeight = height + 'px';
});

function getContainerHeight(containerChildren) {
    let height = 0;

    for ( let a = 0; a <= 3; a++ ) {
        height += containerChildren[a].offsetHeight;
    }

    return height;
}
```

### Edit/Resolution

After looking at the solution provided by **H. Udara** I was able to confirm that my method worked. Leading me to do further debugging.

I then realised that the error was due to there not being a check for if a category has 3 or less awards. After adding in this check and a const to specify the max elements each category should show, the code now works.

```
const containers = document.querySelectorAll( '.award-category-container' );
const maxElems = 4;
for ( let c = 0; c < containers.length; c++) {
    let awards = containers[c].querySelectorAll( '.award' );
    if ( awards.length >= maxElems ) {
        let height = setContainerHeight(awards);
        containers[c].style.maxHeight = height + 'px';
    }
}

// Takes an array of children and uses the total offsetHeight of the first 3 elements to create a height
function setContainerHeight(containerChildren) {
    let height = 0;

    for ( let a = 0; a < maxElems; a++ ) {
        height += containerChildren[a].offsetHeight;
    }

    return height;
}
```

Comment: Please add your html code as well to the question.

Comment: should `a <= 3` not be `a < containerChildren.length`?

Comment: because you are counting to 0, 1, 2, 3 :)

Comment: The count to 3 is intentional because I want each container to be equal to the height of 3 of its children combined. @Sysix

Comment: Sorry, here is a link to a CodePen I just created for additional context [codePen](https://codepen.io/Kaleshe/pen/QWpdJQq) @ZamAbdulVahid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The querySelector returns a static NodeList. So when this code is run, probably only one element is rendered in the page. What you can try doing is adding a timeout to this code. This will help you ***debug*** the issue.

But do not make this your final code. Because you can never be certain of the timeout period. If the network is too slow it could take well over 3 seconds to load the elements. Look into promises or callbacks and implement your final code. If you are making AJAX calls to get data before creating the elements, use the callback provided by AJAX to determine if the AJAX call is complete.

```
const awardCatContainers = document.querySelectorAll( '.award-category-container' );
const button = document.querySelector( '.award .button' );
// set a timeout
setTimeout(() => {awardCatContainers.forEach( (container) => {
    let awards = container.querySelectorAll( '.award' );
    let height = getContainerHeight(awards);

    container.style.maxHeight = height + 'px';
})}, 3000);

function getContainerHeight(containerChildren) {
    let height = 0;

    for ( let a = 0; a <= 3; a++ ) {
        height += containerChildren[a].offsetHeight;
    }

    return height;
}
```

Comment: I am glad it could solve the issue. But do not make this your final code. Because you can never be certain of the timeout period. If the network is too slow it could take well over 3 seconds to load the elements. Look into promises or callbacks and implement your final code. If you are making AJAX calls to get data before creating the elements, use the callback provided by AJAX to determine if the AJAX call is complete.

Comment: Yeah, I was worried about that. Currently trying to figure out how to do it without having to time it out for 3 seconds. Quite frustrating, but thanks for making me aware I wasn't going crazy!

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the awards and apply the styling:

```
awardCatContainers.forEach( (container) => {
    let awards = container.querySelectorAll( '.award' );
    let height = getContainerHeight(awards);

    //container.style.maxHeight = height + 'px';
    for (let award of awards) award.style.maxHeight = height + 'px';
});
```

It's possible that I misunderstood your problem, in which case you will need to provide more information.

`getContainerHeight` is also strange, you go from 0 to 3. It would help a lot in understanding your exact intention if I knew what your structure is.

Comment: The count to 3 is intentional because I want each container to be equal to the height of 3 of its children combined. It looks like it was due to the elements not being ready on page load.